# Span out values emitted by an Observable

Tags: java, observable, intervals, rx-java2, reactivex

I'm a begginer when it comes to ReactiveX, so this question might be trivial, but I haven't found an answer through searching.

I have an observable that emits items quite irregularly (from ~4 times per second to once every 5 seconds) and I want to make sure it never emits an item more often that once per second. I thought about using `zip` operator with `Observable.interval()`, but I realized that if it emits an item after 5 seconds and then emits 3 items in less than a second, all of those items will be emitted in one second.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want. What you end up using depends on you use case.

## throttleLast

`throttle` let's you specify that you only want a new value at a certain interval. This is probably closest to what you were trying to achieve with `zip` and `interval`:

```
myObservable.throttleLast(1, TIMEUNIT.SECOND)
```

This will emit the most recent signal emitted every second. The other signals emitted inside the second are discarded.

## buffer

`buffer` does much the same as `throttleLast`, but instead of passing the most recently emitted value, it will return a `Flowable` with all the values emitted in the timespan.

```
myObservable.buffer(1, TIMEUNIT.SECOND)
```

Comment: So `throttleLast` seems great, but it seems like it's not working for me. I added it right before subscription and the observable emits items like there was no `throttleLast` at all (nothing changed). Could this be issue with threads/schedulers?

Comment: Could you update your question with some code? It shouldn't be affected by schedulers in that manner.

Comment: Nevermind, my code had an error. It all works as it should - thanks!